# Hard to scroll the scrollView in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, scrollview, xcode6

I had created the scrollView and UIButton on it like the code below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    myScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 375, 60)];
    myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(375*4, 60);
    myScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    myScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    myScrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:myScrollView];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4 ; i ++) {
        UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75 + 375*i, 0, 300, 60)];
        [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %d",i+1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [myScrollView addSubview:btn];
    }
}
```

On iphone 6,the scrollView becomes tough to scroll, but when I replace the button by label, It is working normal.

In iphone 5,5s, it's all right;
What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First subclass UIScrollview and add this function to .m file.

```
     - (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view{
if ( [view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] ) {
    return YES;
}
return [super touchesShouldCancelInContentView:view];}
```

use subclass as scrollview

```
myScrollView = [[myScroll alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 375, 60)];
```

Then set this property YES

```
myScrollView.canCancelContentTouches = YES;
```

This solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah,the problem has solved,but how comes the problem like that?Can you explain it to me,or send me email(felixmorgan109@gmail.com).I appreciate it,and thank you very much!